# $.ajax() cannot pass param longer than 512 characters

Tags: jquery, ajax, tinymce

I am trying to save tinyMCE content using jquery Ajax calls.
When I enter plain text, the data gets passed all fine, but when I, for instance, copy some text from http://www.lipsum.com/, the text is not being sent.

This is my jQuery code :

```
var text = escape(tinyMCE.editors['input_news_text_'+n_id].getContent());

console.log(text); // always returns encoded text

$.ajax({
    url         : '/create-school',
    data        : {a : 'update_news_post', id : n_id, place : p_id, s_title : title, s_img : img, s_text : text},
    dataType    : 'json',
    success     : function(o_data){console.log(o_data)}
});
```

And the PHP function (currently) returns

```
print_r($_REQUEST);
```

The returned o_data contains the text from the tinyMCE field if its content doesn't have a whole lot of HTML but only some `<p>` and `<strong>` and such, but if I try to fill in something with more HTML tags, the `$_REQUEST['s_text']` is empty.

Any advice?

Comment: Check your browser's developer tools to see the request being sent out. If the request appears truncated, then it's a front-end issue. If not, it's a back-end issue.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. 
I found out I was _not_ using post. Seems I set the method in a different ajax call.
So with adding
method : 'post' 
It now works.

Comment: Cory and Aurelin, can any of you write that as an answer? (I would but I don't want to take credit for your discovery)

Comment: @SparK "*So I found out that I cannot post a parameter whose value is longer than 512 characters. Even if I use post.*". I'm not sure if OP still stands by this, or if it was because he wasn't actually POSTing in the first place.

Comment: @h2ooooooo _"I found out I was not using post."_ Should we mark it as "too specific"? or are people going to make the same mistakes and end up in this thread?

Comment: I can edit my question to clarify that I was messing up there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding

```
method: 'post'
```

Fixed the issue (thanks Cory for pointing me in the right direction).

So now the ajax call looks as follows :

```
$.ajax({
    url         : '/create-school',
    data        : {a : 'update_news_post', id : n_id, place : p_id, s_title : title, s_img : img, s_text : text},
    dataType    : 'json',
    method      : 'post',
    success     : function(o_data){console.log(o_data)}
});
```

Comment: Not very restful of a uri but good to know it works for you =D
Mark as answer?

Comment: What do you mean?

And yes I will, but I have to wait another 20 hrs before I can mark my own answer.

Comment: if you are creating a new "news post", it makes sense to call ajax to '/school-name/news' with 'post' method to create, 'put'/'update' to 'edit' and 'delete' to delete...
the Rails framework documents it better